# RollBack откатывает транзакции, запущенные на текущей базе или на всех базах сервера?

Tags: sql-server

RollBack откатывает транзакции, запущенные на текущей базе или на всех базах сервера?

На сервере несколько баз данных.
Я подцепилась к своей, создала транзакцию, откатила ее RollBack-ом.
Вопрос: при это не могли откатиться транзакции, запущенные кем-то другим на других базах этого сервера?

Где можно почитать доступно?

Comment: Не счет баз не знаю. Но откатывается только начатая вами транзакция в рамках конкретного подключения

Comment: @Mike в рамках одного подключения может быть сколько угодно транзакций

Comment: @Dmitry, но начатая при этом только одна? или можно запустить одновременно две несвязанные транзакции на одном подключении?

Comment: @BOPOH я же уже ответ написал :)

Comment: @Dmitry, ваш ответ отвечает (почти) на вопрос ТС, а не на мой. В mysql нельзя в том же подключении начать вторую транзакцию - первая закомиттится и начнется новая. Т.е. активной всегда будет только одна, других быть не может. А здесь как?

Comment: @BOPOH ну тут вопрос скорее к подключениям, или возможно к реализации провайдера. MSSQL может держать подключение пока ему не скажешь например Close, но до тех пор пока не скажешь можешь юзать сколь угодно долго. Хотя... надо подумать :)

Comment: @Dmitry, не, "держать подключение" - это значит будет создано еще одно для текущей транзакции. Т.е. подключений будет несколько. А если я сделаю `start transaction; update table...; start transaction; update table2; rollback; commit` - что будет? Откатится вторая транзакция, а первая зафиксируется? Или как? В mysql так нельзя - после второго `start transaction` первая закомитится сразу же и ничего с нею уже сделать нельзя, а здесь?

Comment: @BOPOH думаю у нас разные понятия о подключениях :) но это скорее от того, что MySQL не совсем взрослая база данных, без обид ;)

Comment: @BOPOH кстати, о многопоточных транзакциях в MySQL http://habrahabr.ru/post/115156/

Comment: @Dmitry, для mysql скорее всего создается новое подключение, а не используется старое, т.к. для старого будет следующее: [*Beginning a transaction causes any pending transaction to be committed.*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html)

Answer (score 1):

Откатывается только та транзакция, которая была начата в рамках запроса в котором была выполнена команда `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION`

Более подробно о команде `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` можно прочитать [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms181299(v=sql.120).aspx)

Comment: думаю вопрос был в следующем: начинаем транзакцию, обновляем таблицу в одной базе (schema), а потом обновляем таблицу в другой базе (на том же сервере). Откат транзакции будет же для обеих баз?

Comment: @BOPOH на один `BEGIN` - один `ROLLBACK`

Comment: это понятно, вопрос в другом - для второй базы тоже сработает? т.е. автор хочет увидеть (как я это понял) что транзакция не привязана к базе, поэтому если откатываем транзакцию, то отменятся все изменения, даже на разных базах (одного сервера бд). Т.е. можно смело делать `use db1; start transaction; update db2.users...; rollback`

Comment: @BOPOH ну если перечитать вопрос еще раз с нуля, то ваш вопрос отпадет, речь идет как раз о том что я написал. В вопросе спрашивается, откатятся ли транзакции к другим базам от других юзеров

Comment: а, ну да, слеповат-с )))) я только первое сообщение прочитал )

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ и всем за участие!